# ZSH conflict with Python setuptools extras and pip?

Tags: terminal, bash, python, zsh

I have installed python 3.9.7 using pyenv. I then installed a package `webchanges` [which has optional dependencies to be installed](https://webchanges.readthedocs.io/en/stable/dependencies.html) using `setuptools extras` and `pip` format:

```
pip install --upgrade webchanges[use_browser]
pip install --upgrade webchanges[use_browser,redis]
```

however when using zsh I get this result:

```
$ python -m pip install --upgrade webchanges[use_browser]
zsh: no matches found: webchanges[use_browser]
```

when switching to bash the command completes without issue.

**I am wondering what the message "no matches found" might indicate in relation to zsh? Is there a environmental setting that would confuse `zsh` when using the `setuptools extras` and `pip` syntax?**

here is the full command history:

```
09/19/21_10:30:07 /Users/john
$ pip list
Package    Version
---------- -------
pip        21.2.4
setuptools 58.0.4

09/19/21_10:32:12 /Users/john
$ python -m pip install webchanges
Collecting webchanges
  Using cached webchanges-3.8.3-py3-none-any.whl (86 kB)
Collecting cssselect
  Using cached cssselect-1.1.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (16 kB)
Collecting lxml
  Using cached lxml-4.6.3-cp39-cp39-macosx_10_9_x86_64.whl (4.6 MB)
Collecting html2text
  Using cached html2text-2020.1.16-py3-none-any.whl (32 kB)
Collecting markdown2
  Using cached markdown2-2.4.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (34 kB)
Collecting pyyaml
  Using cached PyYAML-5.4.1-cp39-cp39-macosx_10_9_x86_64.whl (259 kB)
Collecting requests
  Using cached requests-2.26.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (62 kB)
Collecting msgpack
  Using cached msgpack-1.0.2-cp39-cp39-macosx_10_14_x86_64.whl (74 kB)
Collecting platformdirs
  Using cached platformdirs-2.3.0-py3-none-any.whl (13 kB)
Collecting charset-normalizer~=2.0.0
  Using cached charset_normalizer-2.0.6-py3-none-any.whl (37 kB)
Collecting urllib3<1.27,>=1.21.1
  Using cached urllib3-1.26.6-py2.py3-none-any.whl (138 kB)
Collecting certifi>=2017.4.17
  Using cached certifi-2021.5.30-py2.py3-none-any.whl (145 kB)
Collecting idna<4,>=2.5
  Using cached idna-3.2-py3-none-any.whl (59 kB)
Installing collected packages: urllib3, idna, charset-normalizer, certifi, requests, pyyaml, platformdirs, msgpack, markdown2, lxml, html2text, cssselect, webchanges
Successfully installed certifi-2021.5.30 charset-normalizer-2.0.6 cssselect-1.1.0 html2text-2020.1.16 idna-3.2 lxml-4.6.3 markdown2-2.4.1 msgpack-1.0.2 platformdirs-2.3.0 pyyaml-5.4.1 requests-2.26.0 urllib3-1.26.6 webchanges-3.8.3

09/19/21_10:32:32 /Users/john
$ python -m pip install --upgrade webchanges[use_browser]
zsh: no matches found: webchanges[use_browser]


09/19/21_10:35:44 /Users/john
$ bash

The default interactive shell is now zsh.
To update your account to use zsh, please run `chsh -s /bin/zsh`.
For more details, please visit https://support.apple.com/kb/HT208050.
bash-3.2$ python -m pip install --upgrade webchanges[use_browser]
Requirement already satisfied: webchanges[use_browser] in ./.pyenv/versions/3.9.7/lib/python3.9/site-packages (3.8.3)
Requirement already satisfied: pyyaml in ./.pyenv/versions/3.9.7/lib/python3.9/site-packages (from webchanges[use_browser]) (5.4.1)
Requirement already satisfied: lxml in ./.pyenv/versions/3.9.7/lib/python3.9/site-packages (from webchanges[use_browser]) (4.6.3)
Requirement already satisfied: markdown2 in ./.pyenv/versions/3.9.7/lib/python3.9/site-packages (from webchanges[use_browser]) (2.4.1)
Requirement already satisfied: platformdirs in ./.pyenv/versions/3.9.7/lib/python3.9/site-packages (from webchanges[use_browser]) (2.3.0)
Requirement already satisfied: html2text in ./.pyenv/versions/3.9.7/lib/python3.9/site-packages (from webchanges[use_browser]) (2020.1.16)
Requirement already satisfied: requests in ./.pyenv/versions/3.9.7/lib/python3.9/site-packages (from webchanges[use_browser]) (2.26.0)
Requirement already satisfied: msgpack in ./.pyenv/versions/3.9.7/lib/python3.9/site-packages (from webchanges[use_browser]) (1.0.2)
Requirement already satisfied: cssselect in ./.pyenv/versions/3.9.7/lib/python3.9/site-packages (from webchanges[use_browser]) (1.1.0)
Collecting pyppeteer
  Using cached pyppeteer-0.2.6-py3-none-any.whl (83 kB)
Requirement already satisfied: urllib3<2.0.0,>=1.25.8 in ./.pyenv/versions/3.9.7/lib/python3.9/site-packages (from pyppeteer->webchanges[use_browser]) (1.26.6)
Collecting importlib-metadata>=1.4
  Using cached importlib_metadata-4.8.1-py3-none-any.whl (17 kB)
Collecting appdirs<2.0.0,>=1.4.3
  Using cached appdirs-1.4.4-py2.py3-none-any.whl (9.6 kB)
Collecting pyee<9.0.0,>=8.1.0
  Using cached pyee-8.2.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl (12 kB)
Collecting websockets<10.0,>=9.1
  Using cached websockets-9.1-cp39-cp39-macosx_10_9_x86_64.whl (88 kB)
Collecting tqdm<5.0.0,>=4.42.1
  Using cached tqdm-4.62.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl (76 kB)
Collecting zipp>=0.5
  Using cached zipp-3.5.0-py3-none-any.whl (5.7 kB)
Requirement already satisfied: charset-normalizer~=2.0.0 in ./.pyenv/versions/3.9.7/lib/python3.9/site-packages (from requests->webchanges[use_browser]) (2.0.6)
Requirement already satisfied: idna<4,>=2.5 in ./.pyenv/versions/3.9.7/lib/python3.9/site-packages (from requests->webchanges[use_browser]) (3.2)
Requirement already satisfied: certifi>=2017.4.17 in ./.pyenv/versions/3.9.7/lib/python3.9/site-packages (from requests->webchanges[use_browser]) (2021.5.30)
Installing collected packages: zipp, websockets, tqdm, pyee, importlib-metadata, appdirs, pyppeteer
Successfully installed appdirs-1.4.4 importlib-metadata-4.8.1 pyee-8.2.2 pyppeteer-0.2.6 tqdm-4.62.2 websockets-9.1 zipp-3.5.0
bash-3.2$
```

Comment: In zsh [ does pattern matching. OK looks like another reason for me to not use standard shells - I use fish or xonsh for consistent understandable behaviour.

Comment: @mmmmmm Well, or to actually know how the shell works, which you do and the OP does not.  OP, escape the brackets, if they are necessary.

Comment: Actually I don't know how zsh works here - just enough to know not to do it :) I just assume all Unix originating shells are odd and use another language

Answer (score 3, accepted):

TL,DR:

```
pip install --upgrade webchanges\[use_browser]
```

---

`pip install --upgrade webchanges[use_browser]` has mostly the same meaning in bash and zsh: `webchanges[use_browser]` is a wildcard pattern (“glob”). See [bash pattern matching](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Pattern-Matching), [zsh filename generation](https://zsh.sourceforge.io/Doc/Release/Expansion.html#Filename-Generation)). `[…]` means “one character, which is any of the characters between the brackets”. So if the current directory contains the files

```
webchanges webchangesa webchangesb webchangesc webchangesd webchangese webchangeser zebchangese
```

then the shell runs the command

```
pip install --upgrade webchangesb webchangese
```

Where bash and zsh differ is what happens when a pattern doesn't match any file. Bash (and other sh-compatible shells) pass the pattern unchanged to the command. Zsh, by default, signals an error.

The solution, in sh, bash or zsh, is to quote the special character `[` ([bash quoting](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Quoting), [zsh quoting](https://zsh.sourceforge.io/Doc/Release/Shell-Grammar.html#Quoting)). You can quote `]` for symmetry but you don't need to: it only has a special meaning when there's an unquoted `[` before it to close. For example:

```
pip install --upgrade 'webchanges[use_browser]'
pip install --upgrade webchanges\[use_browser]
pip install --upgrade webchanges\[use_browser\]
```

Likewise you need to quote `<` or `>` in a pip requirement specifier so that it isn't parsed as indicating a [redirection](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Redirections). In zsh you also need to quote either of the equal signs in `==` to avoid [equal expansion](https://zsh.sourceforge.io/Doc/Release/Expansion.html#g_t_0060_003d_0027-expansion) if [`magic_equal_subst`](https://zsh.sourceforge.io/Doc/Release/Options.html#index-MAGIC_005fEQUAL_005fSUBST) is enabled and [`equals`](https://zsh.sourceforge.io/Doc/Release/Options.html#index-EQUALS) is not disabled.

```
pip install webchanges\>1.2.3
pip install webchanges\>=1.2.3
pip install webchanges\==1.2.3
pip install webchanges=\=1.2.3
```